# Button not pressed Selenium + Java

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I have a site I want to automate. There is a popup (what before popping up is hidden) with a cancel and ok button. There seems to be no way I can automatically press the ok button (cancel also not).

XPath:

```
//*[@id=\"lightbox\"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/button[2]
```

not working.

[View code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUJfS.jpg)

Comment: Post code, not an image of code.

Comment: Look  the code in attached screenshot, your popup more like opened in a seperate browser window, rather than a part of current page.  If in a seperate window, you need to switch to that window, before you operate any element on it.

Comment: <div id="lightbox" class="lightbox hidden">
<div class="overlay" onclick="escapeLightbox()"></div>
<div class="box">
<div class="lightbox_inner">
<h3 class="title hidden" data-default="Let op"></h3>
<div class="confirm clearfix hidden">
<div class="warn"><i class="icon-warning"></i></div>
<p class="message"></p>
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="no hidden primary">Annuleer</button>
      <button class="yes hidden">Ok</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap" id="lbwrap">

    </div>
    <i class="icon-remove" onclick="escapeLightbox()"></i></div></div></div>

Comment: view-source:https://bl3p.eu/nl/trade

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `XPath`:

```
//button[@class='yes'and contains(.,'Ok')]
```

### Update:

As the normal `Java` click is not working so there may be a overlay. So we will take help of `JavascriptExecutor` as follows:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element_to_be_clicked);
```

Comment: What do i have to fill in at: element_to_be_clicked?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //button[contains(@class,'yes') and contains(text(),'OK')]
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath like this:

```
//button[contains(@class,'yes') and contains(text(),'OK')]
```

Use with `JavascriptExecutor`:

```
WebElement btn= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'yes') and contains(text(),'OK')]"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", btn);
```

Comment: try with JavascriptExecutor

Comment: no success :(  Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //button[contains(@class,'yes') and contains(text(),'OK')]
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: Check whether element is on frame or not